# Rectify "INCLUDE environment variable is empty" scandir

Tags: python

getting the error in scandir installation any suggestions to rectify if

**C:\Python27\scandir-1.5\scandir-1.5>python -m setup.py install**

```
running install
running bdist_egg
running egg_info
writing scandir.egg-info\PKG-INFO
writing top-level names to scandir.egg-info\top_level.txt
writing dependency_links to scandir.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
warning: manifest_maker: standard file '-c' not found

reading manifest file 'scandir.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'    
reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
writing manifest file 'scandir.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
installing library code to build\bdist.win32\egg
running install_lib
running build_py
running build_ext
building '_scandir' extension
error: INCLUDE environment variable is empty
```